# Javascript datepicker inside prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've never seen it before, but I reckon it can be done.
I'm making an application right now, and I use a prompt in javascript to get the requried data, like

```
description = prompt ("insert your description here, please");
```

Now, we want to be able to retrieve a date from a datepicker inside this prompt.
So, prompt comes up, asks for a description, you fill in your description, click ok, and then another prompt box comes up with a datepicker. That's the idea, but it seems impossible to achieve.

Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Comment: don't use `prompt` often user may be annoyed. Try with `modal` http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/modals-tutorial.php

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt check this! Wont help you solve your problem but will at least give you brief info what prompt is.

Comment: You can't do this with a prompt, you want a Jquery UI dialog (or similar) like Ashwin says below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a modal dialog would be more appropriate than a form:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form